# как сделать чтоб 4 оставить активными а 5й скрыть

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

есть такой вот код

```
<?php if(!empty($users_portfolio)):?>
                <div class="recommended_items"><!--recommended_items--><!--category-tab-->
                    <h2 class="title text-center"><a href="/portfolio/allportfolio"><?=$text_users_portfolio?></a></h2>
                    <div id="portfolio-item-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-inner" id="carousel_popular_vacancies">
                            <?php foreach($users_portfolio as $k => $v):?>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 item <?=($k == 0)?'active':''?>">
                                <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                                    <div class="single-products">
                                        <div class="productinfo text-center">
                                            <img src="<?=SITE.$v['portfolio_img']?>" alt="<?=$v['lastname']?> <?=$v['name']?>" />
                                            <h2><?=$v['lastname']?> <?=$v['name']?></h2>
                                            <p><?=$v['adresResident']?></p>
                                            <a href="/portfolio/preview/<?=$v['id_user']?>" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <?=$text_read_more?></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-overlay">
                                            <div class="overlay-content">
                                                <h2><?=$v['lastname']?> <?=$v['name']?></h2>
                                                <p><?=$v['adresResident']?></p>
                                                <a href="/portfolio/preview/<?=$v['id_user']?>" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <?=$text_read_more?></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php endforeach ?>
                        </div>
                    <a href="#portfolio-item-carousel" class="left recommended-item-control" data-slide="prev">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#portfolio-item-carousel" class="right recommended-item-control" data-slide="next">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div><!--/category-tab-->
                <?php endif ?>
```

который выводит 5 div блока. и только 1 из них делает активным, как сделать чтоб 4 оставить активными а 5й скрыть, как слайдер товаров на bootstrap

Comment: `$k == 0` => `$k < 4` ?

Comment: не помогло! не верно это

Comment: если скрыть, то `$k < 4 ? "active" : "d-none"`